# References for a standard result about coverings of Riemann surfaces

Tags: reference-request, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

I my thesis I have to cite the following standard result:

> Let $Y$ be a compact Riemann surface and let $B\subseteq Y$ be a finite subset. Given a natural number $d$, there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of (holomorphic) coverings $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ of degree $d$ and with branch locus contained in $B$.

I need a reference (also a paper), **different from Rick Miranda's book**, in which this theorem is proved.

*Remark*: I think that Miranda's book is a beautiful reference for Riemann surfaces, simply I don't like how the above theorem is presented. In general I'm not comfortable with theorems whose statements are given after the proofs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked in Farkas/Kra? (If you have, there's no point for me to look whether it's in there.)

Comment: I've looked in Farkas/Kra and there isn't the theorem

Comment: The proof is short enough that you can just give it, can't you? If you believe that such a thing is a covering map away from the branch locus then this follows once you believe that $Y \setminus B$ has finitely generated fundamental group, which is clear from Seifert-van Kampen.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  I know the proof, but I'm a bit undecided on writing it in my thesis. In general I can't distinguish between  theorems that must be only cited and those that need an explicit proof. But this is another kind of problem.

Comment: I think it is one of the cases when it is easier to write a proof than to find a reference. If you like, I can give an over the top reference which actually computes the number of such coverings.

Comment: @studiosus I'd like to see your "over the top" reference. Many thanks.

Comment: Dear fair-coin: Can you say what the proof in Miranda's book is, so we know what not to answer?

Comment: In Miranda's book is the proposition 4.9 at page 91. I apologize if my question was not clear.

Answer (score 3):

As requested:

A. D. Mednykh, "Nonequivalent coverings of Riemann surfaces with a prescribed ramification type",  Siberian Mathematical Journal, 1984, Volume 25, Issue 4, pp 606-625. (English translation)

All in all the problem of computing Hurwitz numbers, is a very active area of mathematics, see for instance [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0101147v2.pdf) by A.Okounkov and R.Pandaripande and [this thesis](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~zvonkine/publications/these.ps.gz) by A.Zvonkine.  See also [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~mulase/courses/mat280f09.html) for further  references.